# How to overwrite AutoComplete Style property

Tags: css, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete, styles

```
MuiInput-formControl {
    margin-top: 16px;
```

How can I overwrite the property to have marginTop = 0

I tried the below method but it did not work.

```
MuiFormControlLabel: {
      marginTop: 0,
    },
```

```
<Autocomplete
                  disablePortal
                  classes={{ root: classes.MuiFormControlLabel }}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your Autocomplete, you should use className instead of classes, I revise the code you can try.

```js
    MuiFormControlLabel: {
      marginTop: 0
    }
```

```js
<Autocomplete
 disablePortal
 className={classes.MuiFormControlLabel}
>
```

Comment: It is not working. Thanks

Comment: I think you can try this: <Autocomplete
 disablePortal
 sx={{marginTop: 0}}
/>